Vercel Monorepo Deployment Issue: Frontend 404s When Deployed from Root, API 404s when deployed from client
How can I maintain a monorepo structure while correctly serving both the frontend and API from Vercel? I'd prefer not to split into separate deployments if possible, as the monorepo structure helps with CORS and security issues, particularly in Safari browsers.
Problem Description
I'm working on a MERN stack application with the following structure:
steam-report-mern/
├── api/
│   └── index.js
├── client/
│   ├── dist/
│   ├── src/
│   └── package.json
└── vercel.json

When deploying from the root directory:

✅ API endpoints work correctly (/api/test returns 200)
❌ Frontend routes return 404s
❌ Static assets (CSS/JS) return 404s

However, when deploying from the client directory:

✅ Frontend works perfectly
❌ Can't access the API

What I've Tried
1. Root Deployment Configuration
I have tried most combinations of dist/ and client/ in order to locate the root directory. This is the Vercel file that deploys the API but not the frontend. It seems that distDir has to have the value dist in order to serve the frontend.
I also have this same file in the client directory, which deploys the frontend but not the API.
I'm willing to predict this as the key problem file. Specifically the routes section.
Have 2 builds, one for the API and one for the frontend is espected to solve the issue.
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "api/index.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        },
        {
            "src": "client/package.json",
            "use": "@vercel/static-build",
            "config": {
                "distDir": "dist",
                "buildCommand": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
            }
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/api/(.*)",
            "dest": "/api/index.js"
        },
        {
            "src": "/assets/(.*)",
            "dest": "/dist/assets/$1"
        },
        {
            "handle": "filesystem"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/dist/index.html"
        }
    ]
}

1.2 Package.json:
I've tried setting up the start script to run the build command in the client directory.
{
  "dependencies": {
    "docsify": "^4.13.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
    "repo-to-one-file": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node api/index.js && cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "vercel-build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  }
}

1.3 Vite config:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    assetsDir: 'assets',
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
  base: '',
  css: {
    postcss: {
     plugins: [tailwindcss],
    },
   },
});

2. Verification Tests
# API works
curl -I https://steamreport.lauriecrean.dev/api/test
# Returns 200 OK

# Frontend fails
curl -I https://steamreport.lauriecrean.dev/
# Returns 404 Not Found

# Assets fail
curl -I https://steamreport.lauriecrean.dev/assets/index-212a1c80.css
# Returns 404 Not Found

3. Build Output
The build process completes successfully:
PS C:\Projects\steam-report-mern> vercel build 
Vercel CLI 35.1.0
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+
Running "npm run vercel-build"

> client@0.0.0 vercel-build
> vite build

vite v4.3.3 building for production...
✓ 157 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                                 0.47 kB │ gzip:  0.31 kB
dist/assets/index-212a1c80.css                249.45 kB │ gzip: 35.03 kB
dist/assets/personalityQuestions-7ebff02e.js    6.98 kB │ gzip:  2.78 kB
dist/assets/index-73d86b56.js                 255.70 kB │ gzip: 83.07 kB
✓ built in 1.71s
Installing dependencies...

up to date in 696ms

✅  Build Completed in .vercel\output [9s]

Environment

Vite for frontend build
Node.js backend
Vercel CLI 35.1.0
Node v20.5.1
npm 10.2.5

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
Codebase: https://github.com/lmcrean/steam-report-mern
Error Messages in full for CURL VERIFICATION TESTS

PS C:\Projects\steam-report-mern> curl -I https://steamreport.lauriecrean.dev/

cmdlet Invoke-WebRequest at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Uri: 
PS C:\Projects\steam-report-mern> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://steamreport.lauriecrean.dev/" -Method HEAD
>>                                                              Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (404)  Not Found.                                                      At line:1 char:1                                                
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 
"https://steamreport.lauriecrean.dev/" -Method ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Ht 
   tpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExcep  
  tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Mi 
   crosoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
 
PS C:\Projects\steam-report-mern> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://steamreport.lauriecrean.dev/assets/index-212a1c80.css" -Method HEAD
>> 
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (404) 
Not Found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 
"https://steamreport.lauriecrean.dev/assets/in ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Ht 
   tpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExcep  
  tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Mi 
   crosoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

PS C:\Projects\steam-report-mern> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://steamreport.lauriecrean.dev/api/test" -Method HEAD
>>


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           :
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,       
                    X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept      
                    Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
                    GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
                    Age: 0
                    Str...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,     
                    X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept],    
                    [Access-Control-Allow-Methods,
                    GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE],
                    [Access-Control-Allow-Origin, *], [Age,     
                    0]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : System.__ComObject
RawContentLength  : 0



PS C:\Projects\steam-report-mern> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://steamreport.lauriecrean.dev/index.html" -Method HEAD
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (404)     
Not Found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri
"https://steamreport.lauriecrean.dev/index.htm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    
~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Ht     
   tpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExcep      
  tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Mi     
   crosoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

3.1 Vercel Build Output
[18:00:26.215] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[18:00:27.163] Retrieving list of deployment files...
[18:00:28.592] Downloading 5574 deployment files...
[18:01:16.189] Restored build cache from previous deployment (9HU6RPtTe5k1ujqAvye6vj2EWBZK)
[18:01:16.384] Running "vercel build"
[18:01:18.249] Vercel CLI 39.1.1
[18:01:19.176] WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
[18:01:21.023] Installing dependencies...
[18:01:22.491] npm warn EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
[18:01:22.491] npm warn EBADENGINE   package: 'amqplib@0.5.2',
[18:01:22.492] npm warn EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=0.8 <=9' },
[18:01:22.493] npm warn EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v20.18.1', npm: '10.8.2' }
[18:01:22.493] npm warn EBADENGINE }
[18:01:23.285] 
[18:01:23.286] up to date in 2s
[18:01:23.286] 
[18:01:23.287] 122 packages are looking for funding
[18:01:23.287]   run `npm fund` for details
[18:01:23.309] Running "npm run vercel-build"
[18:01:26.071] 
[18:01:26.077] > client@0.0.0 vercel-build
[18:01:26.082] > vite build
[18:01:26.086] 
[18:01:26.795] [36mvite v4.3.3 [32mbuilding for production...[36m[39m
[18:01:26.834] transforming...
[18:01:30.702] [32m✓[39m 157 modules transformed.
[18:01:30.883] rendering chunks...
[18:01:31.082] computing gzip size...
[18:01:31.159] [2mdist/[22m[32mindex.html                               [39m[1m[2m  0.47 kB[22m[1m[22m[2m │ gzip:  0.31 kB[22m
[18:01:31.160] [2mdist/[22m[2massets/[22m[35mindex-212a1c80.css                [39m[1m[2m249.45 kB[22m[1m[22m[2m │ gzip: 34.87 kB[22m
[18:01:31.161] [2mdist/[22m[2massets/[22m[36mpersonalityQuestions-7ebff02e.js  [39m[1m[2m  6.98 kB[22m[1m[22m[2m │ gzip:  2.75 kB[22m
[18:01:31.161] [2mdist/[22m[2massets/[22m[36mindex-73d86b56.js                 [39m[1m[2m255.70 kB[22m[1m[22m[2m │ gzip: 83.12 kB[22m
[18:01:31.164] [32m✓ built in 4.37s[39m
[18:01:31.244] Installing dependencies...
[18:01:32.585] 
[18:01:32.586] up to date in 1s
[18:01:32.586] 
[18:01:32.586] 57 packages are looking for funding
[18:01:32.587]   run `npm fund` for details
[18:01:35.642] Build Completed in /vercel/output [15s]
[18:01:36.055] Deploying outputs...
[18:01:42.986] 
[18:01:43.262] Deployment completed
[18:02:11.930] Uploading build cache [46.76 MB]...
[18:02:12.571] Build cache uploaded: 641.226ms

